# Calculating Revenue Growth in Oracle for Quarter 1 vs Quarter 2

Tags: sql, oracle

Calculating Revenue Growth in Oracle for Quarter 1 vs Quarter 2 ->
I have a sales table with columns of dt_invoice_date, sale value. 
How can I do it in Oracle. The code for yearly revenue growth that I used was -

```sql
select yr1, yr2, sales1,sales2, (sales1-sales2)/sales2*100 as growth

from 
(select extract(year from dt_invoice_date)  yr1, sum(sale_value) as sales1 from base_sales_data_tbl  
group by  extract(year from dt_invoice_date) )S1

left outer join
 (select  extract(year from dt_invoice_date)  yr2, sum(sale_value) as sales2 from base_sales_data_tbl 
 group by extract(year from dt_invoice_date)
 ) S2
 ON yr1-1= yr2 ;
```

In a similar manner how can I calculate Qtr1 vs Qtr2 revenue growth in Oracle. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
    with s1 as (select sum(s.sale_value) sales, to_char(dt_invoice_date,'yyyyq') yrq, lag(sum(s.sale_value),1) over (order by to_char(dt_invoice_date,'yyyyq')) sales_pq
    from base_sales_data_tbl s
    -- added to restrict dates to 1st and 2nd quarter
    where to_char (dt_invoice_date,'q') < 3
    group by to_char(dt_invoice_date,'yyyyq'))
    select yrq, lag(yrq,1) over (order by yrq) prev_q, sales, sales_pq, round((sales-sales_pq)*100/sales_pq,2) growth
    from s1
    order by yrq;
```

Comment: The group by clause should come on year so that there's no repetition of years.

Comment: My solution was for the quarter sales case. For the yearly sales, use the 'YYYY' format in the to_char instead of 'YYYYQ'

Comment: My question is what is the revenue growth qtr1 vs qtr2 in each year.  --------------     "Year / Qtr1 sales/ Qtr 2 sales/ Growth" E.g.  "2019/ QTr1 Sales/ Qtr2 Sales/ Growth( Frm Qtr1 to Qtr2)"

Comment: My query computes growth for each quarter compared to previous one. If you need just quarter 1 and quarter 2, then restrict your dates to these. The query in your question compares every year to the previous one. So I wrote you a SQL to compare every quarter to the previous one.

Comment: How can I restrict it in this code ? By using where clause?? I am new to oracle / sql therefore facing trouble. Kindly help.

Comment: Just edited the answer to do so, but the results will still compare q1 to q2 of the previous year. In the end, I suggest your read a bit more about SQL, otherwise you're going to spend an inordinate time on these sites.

Comment: I had understood the logic and was tying in the same manner to restrict the quarters but since I am new, my syntax was throwing errors . Can you please suggest me some good source from where I can learn.

Comment: I've got no experience with SQL books/sites on the net, so cannot really help here. Others on this site may be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to calculate the quarter and group by year and quarter:

```sql
select qtr1, yr1, qtr2, yr2, sales1,sales2, (sales1-sales2)/sales2*100 as growth

from 
(select extract(year from dt_invoice_date)  yr1, TRUNC(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt_invoice_date) / 3) qtr1, sum(sale_value) as sales1 from base_sales_data_tbl  
group by  extract(year from dt_invoice_date), TRUNC(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt_invoice_date) / 3)
)S1

left outer join
 (select  extract(year from dt_invoice_date)  yr2, TRUNC(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt_invoice_date) / 3) qtr2, sum(sale_value) as sales2 from base_sales_data_tbl 
 group by extract(year from dt_invoice_date), TRUNC(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt_invoice_date) / 3)
 ) S2
 ON (yr1 = yr2 
AND qtr1-1 = qtr2)
OR (yr1-1 = yr2
AND qtr1 = 1
AND qtr2 = 4);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error-ORA-00904: "QRT2": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 75 Column: 14